# Is there anything I need to be cautious with when minifying a website's CSS and Javascript?

Tags: javascript, web, css, wordpress

Planning to minify CSS and Javascript for a [car detailing website](http://www.signaturedetailers.com/) that I recently created. My goal is to increase site speed. It's my first time doing it and I wonder what's the worst that can happen.

Comment: The worst that can happen is that your site uses the old (non-minified) versions instead of the new versions. There's no reason to remove the existing files until you're confident in the process. If you want, you can change one url at a time to point to the new minified URL, and watch what happens. Good luck!

Comment: Welcome to [so]! As asked, your question is too broad to give a full answer. The reader has to make many assumptions about your technical ability, and the technical limitations of your environment to give a complete answer, without also writing a book on the topic.

Comment: @jpaugh Except this is not Stack Overflow. Programming questions are off topic here.

Answer (score 0):

There are no problems. 
You must preserve the original files so if the website presents strange behaviors you can point again to the original files.

Keep in mind that even a simple change in CSS or Javascript is very difficult to achieve on the minified file, so all the modifications must be done on the original files and you will need to minify them again.

Answer (score 0):

The risks you run into will entirely depend on which minifier you choose to use. Different algorithms will produce different results, and have different bugs.

In particular, certain optimizations can cause issues particularly with the cascade. Take for example:

```
.foo {
  color: blue;
}
.bar {
  color: green;
}
.baz {
  color: blue;
}
```

Minifying this code in a minifier that attemps to combine equivalent selectors could lead to:

```
.foo,.baz{color:#00f}.bar{color:#0f0}
```

which would be problematic if your markup has something like:

```
<div class="bar baz">Lorem ipsum</div>
```